# How to setup and access internal services in hooks using FeathersJs

Tags: javascript, knex.js, feathersjs, feathers-hook, feathers-service

I want to use internally defined services in hooks added to public REST endpoints, is this possible?

By internally defined I'm referring to using the **disallow** hook from feathers-common-hooks.

> app.service('/api/internal/helper').hooks( { before: { all: disallow('rest') } } )

The hook looks at the `provider` in the `context` object, if it matches what I've disabled. I.e if **disallow('rest')** is used then it disables the service from being accessed from REST.

The problem is I want to use this internal `helper` service in a hook that is attached to a public service, but haven't found a way to do so. When the internal service is called the `provider` is still **rest** and the call is blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What those hooks do is look for [params.provider](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params) being set. Anything where `params.provider` is not set is considered an internal call. If you want to pass other params along to the internal call you can e.g. [_.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omit) the `provider` property:

```
app.service('/api/internal/helper').find(omit(context.params, 'provider'))
```

Comment: Aaah, how did I miss that. Thanks for the fast response and pointing it out, much appreciated :)